# JUnit 5 test for Soap Web Service - ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered

Tags: java, web-services, soap, junit, junit5

Am trying to create a JUnit 5 test for a published .NET Soap Web Service using Java 1.8.

Currently, I am following a pattern from a WebServiceClient in the codebase which contains a `main()` method.

---

WebServiceClient.java:

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

public class WebServiceClient {
    
    IPersonWebService service;

    public WebServiceClient(IPersonWebService service) {
        this.service = checkNotNull(service);
    }

    private PersonData getPersonData() throws Exception {
        return service.getPersons(null);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        IPersonWebService service = new IPersonWebServiceImpl().getBasicHttpBindingIPersonWebServiceImpl();

        WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient(service);
        PersonData personData = client.getPersonData();
        System.out.println(personData.toString());
    }
}
```

---

Need to following the same type of functionality in:

WebServiceTest.java:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

public class WebServiceTest {

    IPersonWebService service;

    public WebServiceTest(IPersonWebService service) {
        this.service = checkNotNull(service);
    }

    @Before
    public void before(IPersonWebService service) {
        this.service = checkNotNull(service);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPersonData() throws Exception {
        IPersonWebService service =
                new IPersonWebServiceImpl().getBasicHttpBindingIPersonWebServiceImpl();

        WebServiceTest client = new WebServiceTest(service);
        PersonData personData = client.getPersonData();
        assertThat(personData).isNotNull();

    }

    private PersonData getPersonData() throws Exception {
        return service.getPersonData(null);
    }
}
```

---

Running this within IntelliJ IDEA results in:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [com.myapp.IPersonWebService arg0] in constructor [public com.myapp.WebServiceTest(com.myapp.IPersonWebService)].
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
```

---

IPersonWebService.java:

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "IPersonWebService", targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface IPersonWebService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetPersonData", 
               action = "http://sample.org/IPersonWebService/GetPersonData")
    @WebResult(name = "GetVehiclesResult", 
               targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetPersonData", 
                    targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/", 
                    className = "com.myapp.GetPersonData")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetPersonDataResponse", 
                     targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/", 
                     className = "com.myapp.GetPersonDataResponse")
    public {PersonData} getPersonData(
            @WebParam(name = "applicationID", 
                      targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/")
                      String applicationID)
        throws IPersonWebServicetExceptionFaultMessage;
}
```

---

This contains the actual WSDL that will be imported into memory.

IPersonWebServiceImpl.java:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;

/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b130926.1035
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 *
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "IPersonWebServiceImpl", 
                  targetNamespace = "http://sample.org/", 
                  wsdlLocation = "https://sample.com/WCF/IPersonWebServiceImpl.svc?singleWsdl")
public class IPersonWebServiceImpl
    extends Service
{

    private final static URL IPersonWebServiceImpl_WSDL_LOCATION;
    private final static WebServiceException IPersonWebServiceImpl_EXCEPTION;
    private final static QName IPersonWebServiceImpl_QNAME = new QName("http://sample.org/", "IPersonWebServiceImpl");

    static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://sample.com/WCF/IPersonWebServiceImpl.svc?singleWsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            e = new WebServiceException(ex);
        }
        IPersonWebServiceImpl_WSDL_LOCATION = url;
        IPersonWebServiceImpl_EXCEPTION = e;
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl() {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), IPersonWebServiceImpl_QNAME);
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl(final WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(__getWsdlLocation(), IPersonWebServiceImpl_QNAME, features);
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl(final URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, IPersonWebServiceImpl_QNAME);
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl(final URL wsdlLocation, 
                                 final WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, IPersonWebServiceImpl_QNAME, features);
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl(final URL wsdlLocation, 
                                 final QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public IPersonWebServiceImpl(final URL wsdlLocation, 
                                 final QName serviceName, 
                                 final WebServiceFeature... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IPersonWebServiceImpl")
    public IPersonWebServiceImpl getBasicHttpBindingIPersonWebServiceImpl() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://sample.org/", 
                                       "BasicHttpBinding_IPersonWebServiceImpl"), 
                                       IPersonWebServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = "BasicHttpBinding_IPersonWebServiceImpl")
    public IPersonWebServiceImpl getBasicHttpBindingIPersonWebServiceImpl(final WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://sample.org/", 
                                       "BasicHttpBinding_IPersonWebServiceImpl"), 
                                       IPersonWebServiceImpl.class, features);
    }

    private static URL __getWsdlLocation() {
        if (IPersonWebServiceImpl_EXCEPTION!= null) {
            throw IPersonWebServiceImpl_EXCEPTION;
        }
        return IPersonWebServiceImpl_WSDL_LOCATION;
    }
}
```

---

Question(s):

- When trying to follow along using the pattern inside `WebServiceClient.java`, why does `WebServiceTest.java` fail with this:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: 
    No ParameterResolver registered for parameter...
```

How to resolve this?

---

The `WebServiceClient.java` works and shows PersonData which was obtained from the `IPersonWebServiceImpl.java` (notice how this has the WSDL explicitly setup inside the static clause).

- Is there a 3rd party open source Java framework which I can use to import any type of WSDL (.NET or others) and test SOAP based endpoints using JUnit 5?

Come from a RESTful Web Services background and not a SOAP based background, so any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

So firstly, thanks for providing loads of code and making your question clear. I see it's been a few months since you asked, but I'll try and help.

I think there's two problems: the exception (tldr it's a junit version clash), and structuring code for writing unit tests.

### ParameterResolutionException

`@Test` is imported from JUnit5, aka 'junit-jupiter', but `@Before` is from JUnit4, aka 'junit-vintage' or 'junit'.

```java
import org.junit.Before; // junit4
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll; // junit5
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; // junit5
```

Because the `@Test` is from junit-jupiter, the tests are run with JUnit5, which (unlike JUnit4) allows for parameters in test and constructors methods. `WebServiceTest`'s constructor needs a parameter. But you don't have a provider for `IPersonWebService`, so JUnit5 breaks - it can't resolve it.

So to fix this:

- remove the constructor
- remove the parameter from the `before` method
- change `@Before` to `@BeforeEach` (and fix the imports)

---

I'd also recommend (if possible) that you exclude any JUnit4 dependencies that you might have added (`junit-vintage` is for backwards compatibility), or might have been snuck in from other dependencies. It prevents confusions like this.

For example with maven, to see which JUnit versions there are, and their origins, view and filter the dependency tree:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="*junit*"
```

### Writing unit tests

I'm not sure what the application is intended to be, but (as I think you've found out) it's difficult to test. It certainly looks strange to me. `WebServiceClient` has a main method (I guess it gets called directly?) that immediately creates the API and calls it and returns the result - so there's no separation between the 'business logic' and 'api'. Maybe that main method is there for demonstrating?

It would be best to split things up. Hopefully then it makes testing more clear.

---

Let's make a dedicated `WebServiceClient`. This should be the only class that interacts with `IPersonWebService`.

There shouldn't be any sort of fancy logic in here, just simple API calls with basic exception handling.

```java
// import generated soap stuff

public class WebServiceClient {

  private final IPersonWebService service;

  public WebServiceClient(IPersonWebService service) {
    // an instance of the API is received in the constructor
    this.service = service;
  }

  private PersonsData getPersonData() throws WebServiceClientException {
    try {
      // call the API
      PersonsData persons = service.getPersonData(null);
      if (personsData == null) {
        throw new WebServiceClientException("Received null response from PersonsData :(");
      }
      return persons;
    } catch (IPersonWebServicetExceptionFaultMessage e) {
      // wrap the SOAP exception in our own wrapper
      // it's best not to let SOAP code spread into our project.
      throw new WebServiceClientException("Tried fetching PersonsData, but got exception from API", e);
    }
  }
}
```

---

And here's the test class for that service.

Each `@Test` method is completely independent from the others, it has its own little bubble to keep the tests independent.

I really recommend using a mocking framework, like Mockito, to create dummy instances. It's really powerful. In this case it means we can easily test exceptions. Mockito 3 works *really* well with JUnit5 - I've used the parameter injection here to make mocks for the tests (Mockito provides a Parameter Resolver under the hood).

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class WebServiceClientTest {

  @Test
  public void testWebServiceClientCreated(
      // it's not actually important about the internal workings of IPersonWebService
      // so use mockito to mock it!
      // all we care about is that if it's there, then WebServiceClient can be created
      @Mock
          IPersonWebService service) {
    WebServiceClient wsc = new WebServiceClient(service);
    assertNotNull(wsc);
  }

  // test happy flow
  @Test
  public void testPersonsDataReturned(
      // again, we don't care about the internals of IPersonWebService, just that it returns data
      // so mock it!
      @Mock
      IPersonWebService service,

      // it's also not important about the internals of PersonsData,
      // just that it's an object that's returned
      @Mock
      PersonsData personsDataMock) {
    // set up the mock
    when(service.getPersonsData(isNull())).thenReturn(personsDataMock);

    WebServiceClient wsc = new WebServiceClient(service);

    // we don't need to check WebServiceClient here! We already have a test that does this.
    // each test should only focus on one thing
    // assertNotNull(wsc);

    PersonsData result = wsc.getPersonsData();

    // now we can check the result
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(personsDataMock, result);
  }

  // again, testing for failure is much more interesting than happy flows
  // in this case, the test will fail!
  // we'd better fix WebServiceClient to handle unexpected exceptions from IPersonWebService
  @Test
  public void testWhenApiThrowsNullPointerExceptionExpectWebServiceClientException(
      @Mock
      IPersonWebService service) {
    // mock throwing an exception
    NullPointerException npe = new NullPointerException("Another one of those weird external webservice exceptions");
    doThrow()
        .when(service.getPersonsData(isNull()));

    WebServiceClient wsc = new WebServiceClient(service);
    
    WebServiceClientException thrownException = assertThrows(WebServiceClientException.class,
        () -> wsc.getPersonsData()
    );

    // now we can check the result
    assertNotNull(thrownException);
    assertEquals("Tried fetching PersonsData, but got exception from API", thrownException.getMessage());
    assertEquals(npe, thrownException.getCause());
  }
}
```

---

And a nice wrapper for any exceptions when dealing with the API.

```java
class WebServiceClientException extends Exception {

  public WebServiceClientException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public WebServiceClientException(String message, Exception cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }
}
```